# Need help to generate time series with defined interval in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table that has start date, end date and month interval. I need to generate series based on adding interval to start date.

Example:

> 1. Start Date = 5/1/2018, End Date = 12/31/2019, Interval = 2

Series I am looking for (dates in rows): 7/31/18, 9/30/18, 11/30/18, ... 11/30/19

> 2. Start Date = 1/1/2018, End Date = 12/31/19, Interval = 3

Series I am looking for (dates in rows): 3/31/18, 6/30/18, 9/30/18, 12/31/18...12/21/19

Details: I have 3 tables that are joined (inner). First table has start date, second table gives me end date of given customer and 3rd table gives me billing frequency. Based are those 3 parameters I need to predict how many invoices and on what dates we will generate invoices to each customer.

Comment: Could you please clarify: how is your series defined? E.g. "I need to generate a series *of the dates of the second Wednesday of every <interval> month in between <start> and <end>*". Also: Please provide us the code that you tried so far, and the output that it gave :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't super clear but you can try something like this. Just plug in your start_date, end_date, and interval. It will give you mostly what you want, then you can customize for your specific case:

```
with series as (
    select generate_series(1, datediff(month, <start_date>, <end_date>), 1) as n, MOD(n, <interval>) as remainder
  )
select dateadd(month, n, <start_date>) from series where remainder = 0;
```

So an example would be:

```
with series as (
    select generate_series(1, datediff(month, '2018-05-01', '2019-12-31'), 1) as n, MOD(n, 3) as remainder
  )
select dateadd(month, n, '2018-05-01') from series where remainder = 0;
```

Comment: Thank for the script but the problem is the minute I add my base table to get dates I get following error

ERROR: 0A000: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Redshift is not allowing generate_series with any other tables

Comment: I ran that query on Redshift and it worked for me. If you're trying to create a table using it then it failed (I'm not sure why, probably some limitation put in place by Redshift), although I have no issue joining to other tables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not clear but assuming the requirement is `to create month end dates between start and end dates with the given interval as months`

The first example in that case is not correct it should start with `6/1/2018` not `5/1/2018`

The SQL I have is

```
WITH params(start_dt, end_date, interval_) AS
(SELECT '2018-06-01'::date,
        '2019-12-31'::date,
        '2'::integer)
, dates AS 
(SELECT ADD_MONTHS(start_dt, n * interval_) - 1 AS dt
  FROM params ,
       (SELECT generate_series(1, ((datediff(month, start_dt::date, end_date::date) / interval_) + 1)) n 
          FROM params) )
SELECT to_char(dt,'MM/DD/YY') dt
  FROM dates, params
 WHERE dt BETWEEN start_dt AND end_date
```

The output for this is

```
dt
07/31/18
09/30/18
11/30/18
01/31/19
03/31/19
05/31/19
07/31/19
09/30/19
11/30/19
```

For second example

```
WITH params(start_dt, end_date, interval_) AS
(SELECT '2018-01-01'::date,
        '2019-12-31'::date,
        '3'::integer)
, dates AS 
(SELECT ADD_MONTHS(start_dt, n * interval_) - 1 AS dt
  FROM params ,
       (SELECT generate_series(1, ((datediff(month, start_dt::date, end_date::date) / interval_) + 1)) n 
          FROM params) )
SELECT to_char(dt,'MM/DD/YY') dt
  FROM dates, params
 WHERE dt BETWEEN start_dt AND end_date
```

The output is

```
dt
03/31/18
06/30/18
09/30/18
12/31/18
03/31/19
06/30/19
09/30/19
12/31/19
```